# An application of the open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, open-map

> Let $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ be a domain and $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ with $a^2+b^2>0$. Determine all on $U$ holomorphic functions $f$ which
>   satisfy:
>
> $a\cdot Re(f) + b\cdot Im(f) +c = 0$.

I should use the open mapping theorem, which says that $f(U)$ is a domain if $U$ is a domain and $f$ a nonconstant holomorphic function. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your hypotheses imply $f(U) \subset L,$ where $L$ is a familiar geometric object.

Comment: L is a line? right?

Comment: $U\cap \{a\cdot Re(f)+b\cdot Im(f) + c= 0\}$ is a line. Still not able to proceed... :(

Comment: No, you don't want to intersect with $U.$ What we know is $f(U)\subset \{(x,y): ax +by+ c = 0\}.$ The latter is a line in the plane. And a line contains no open subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ Proceed ...